# I want to have a mana system in my game. How would I go about doing that?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I want to create  a mana system in my batch based role-playing game. I'm completely lost as to how I would do that.

For example, I've tried something like this:

```
if errorlevel 2 if %mana%=100 goto :killdemon  
if errorlevel 2 if %mana=10 goto :killbydemon
```

But  if I were to hit 2 it just ends.

I'm apparently supposed to show some code here. I'm new here.
I guess I'll just say the same thing:

I've tried this:

```
set mana=100

:game  
choice /C 12
if errorlevel 2 if %mana%=100 goto :killdemon   
if errorlevel 2 if %mana=10 goto :killbydemon  
if errorlevel 1 goto :eof
```

The actual result is that the cmd closes and thats that. What I want to happen is for the game to send me to the correct part.

Comment: Post this under SuperUser forum also..

Comment: @ChrisCatignani - Why would this get posted to SuperUser? This question is wildly off topic for there.

Comment: Run the script from the command prompt instead of double-clicking on the script. This way, the command prompt will stay open when the script crashes and you can see what the error is. (I imagine it has to do with that missing `%` you have in `if %mana=10`.)

Comment: @somethingdark this is what shows when running from cmd: '100' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
=10 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Use `==` when comparing things. `=` is for setting values.

Comment: so i did `set %mana%=100

:Test  
choice /C 12  
if errorlevel 2 goto :eof  
if errorlevel 1 if %mana%==100 goto :killdemon  
if errorlevel 1 if %mana%==10 goto :killbydemon  

:killdemon  
echo _  

:killbydemon  
echo _/` and it just shows both of the goto segments. I'm a bit lost here haha.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani - Because this question has nothing to do with system administration, software, or hardware. https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It's just `set mana=100`, not `set %mana%=100`. Also, batch scripts run from the top down, so one label goes to the next label unless you tell it to go somewhere else

Comment: @SomethingDark...waves white flag.